# How do I import a Tiled tile map to my XCode project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS development, so I'm trying to learn iOS game design from the ground up. My first goal is to make an OpenGL ES app that does one thing: display a tile map. I made a map using Tiled, and I've been trying to figure out how to import it into my XCode project, but I can't find any good up-to-date tutorials. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The best game engine that supports tile maps is COCOS2D,
found here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cocos2d-iphone.org%2F&ei=v23GT9H0BqnA2gXDwsTYAQ&usg=AFQjCNEUx9C3mwhsRRKQWFiepw3aHvrzwA&sig2=h84PTR8IQ1xghM1pnmmGWw 
 
A good tutorial is http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d
Once you start using cocos2d, tile map tutorials are easy to find and the implementation is relatively easy too! Hope this helped!